# Connect to DNS names trough SSL and manually specify IP of the DNS record (Local DNS poisoning/Spoofing)

Tags: powershell, ssl, dns, adfs, nslookup

I'm currently working on a script that will test the health of an ADFS service. The ADFS service uses the same domain name (split brain DNS) for both intranet access, as well as for public DNS (for internet connections through the proxy servers). If I'm logged into an intranet device and I attempt to perform an SSL connection to the ADFS service, my device will use the intranet IP of the service. If I do the same from a device that is not in the intranet, I will connect to the public facing IP.

I want my script to test the health of both the internal and external service, but I haven't found a way to perform an SSL connection to a certain hostname/fqdn, and use an specific IP depending on the test I'm trying to perform (intranet vs extranet). Connecting directly to the internal/external IP address is not an option, since the ip addresses are not part of the SSL cert subject alternative names.

One option I found Is to create a PS Session to a remote host that has public DNS servers configured, and execute my Extranet test through that PS Session, but Ideally, I would like to run both tests from one single server.

I'm trying to find an option that works in the context of my PowerShell session only, I don't want to change the DNS settings of the server or the global DNS cache since that will result in problems on the server, because it depends on that ADFS service for other services to work.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: As long as the hostname is resolved to the correct IP address and the certificate contains an subjaltname that matches that hostname everything should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to achieve exactly what I asked, so instead, what I did was to deploy a small Rest API in Azure which calls my ADFS service. When I call that Rest API, ADFS receives the query from the Internet, allowing me to achieve test the health of my ADFS service from the internet.